# What is a proper response to "Good luck with X"?

Tags: phrase-choice

What is a proper response to "Good luck with X"?

Example:

> Hi Franck, thanks for sharing the paper draft with me. Good luck with the submission! Bob

Is it ok to reply with "You're welcome, thanks for the wishes"? Are there any preferable alternatives?

Note that replying with "You too" does not make sense if Bob hasn't submitted anything.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious and basic response to anyone wishing one good luck on any occasion is "thank you" or any of its many variants. "You too" can be added when appropriate, but would not be if the other person is not in the situation, whatever it is, for which good luck is being wished. The example response in the question is perfectly appropriate for the example wish.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there were some more specific variant of "thank you", as if the message is long, saying thank you might not be specific enough to indicate that the thank you was regarding the good luck.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt One could say 'Thanks for the good wishes" or "thanks, i'll do my best"  or any similar phrase.